# several questions about fstream in c++

Tags: c++, stream

First, I'm interested in what is best way for working with big files, is this code at bottom recommended way ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file("first.exe", ios::binary | ios::app);
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    char content[size];
    file.read(content, size);
    ofstream file2("second.exe", ios::binary);
    file2.write(content, size);
    file2.close();
}
```

also, why is necessary to use binary mode in this case ?

Comment: Can't be the best way, it's not valid C++, you've got a VLA there - that's C99 and above, but not C++11 (maybe C++14 though?). Also what if the file is larger than your RAM?

Comment: This code will simply not work for large files. You read the whole file to memory. What if the file is larger than your memory?

Comment: As for the binary mode question: is that file a binary file?

Comment: can u write a simple code that's better than this, i want to learn

Comment: `std::ofstream("second.exe") << std::ifstream("first.exe", std::ios_base::binary).rdbuf()`

Comment: @Mat afaik VLA were dropped from the c++14 proposal and will be added later on as specification, so not even valid c++14

Comment: @0x499602D2 shouldn't the ofstream be binary?

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, it should be. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the recommended way?  Not really.  See below.

Binary mode?

There are two ways to open a file: Text mode and Binary mode.  The default is Text mode, unless you use `std::ios::binary` when opening the file.

On Linux/Unix binary mode and text mode are identical.  It makes no difference.

On Windows, when a file is opened in Text mode the o/s does some transformations.  When you write a `\n` (ASCII 10) it gets converted to a `\r\n` pair (ASCII 10 and 13).  When you read a `\r\n` pair, it gets converted to a single `\n`.  Also `Ctl-Z` (ASCII 26) is treated as end of file so reading will terminate.

The reasons for this are historical and I won't go into detail now.  If you read and write plain ASCII text, this causes no problems and can even be desirable.  If you are working with anything else (e.g. an exe file) it is **essential** that you use binary mode.

The code below demonstrates a simple technique for file i/o that tries to capture the essence of C++ programming.  I hope it is reasonably self-explanatory.  Lookup reference for [std::copy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/) and [std::ostreambuf_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator/) and ask questions if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream fsIn("first.exe", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream fsOut("second.exe", std::ios::binary|std::ios::trunc);

    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fsIn), 
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), 
              std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fsOut));
    return 0;
}
```